# Can svn log be run with explicit credentials passed via basic auth?

Tags: svn, authentication, teamcity

I'm having some dramas running svn log from a TeamCity server which I've previously asked about in [Why does the TeamCity command line runner execute under “System”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448680/why-does-the-teamcity-command-line-runner-execute-under-system)

With no evidence to the contrary, it looks like when svn log is invoked by the build server it runs under the local system account which doesn't have access to the SVN repository. Although not ideal, it looks like the only way to make this work is to pass the credentials in the svn log command.

The [documentation for SVN 1.0](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re15.html) shows username and password parameters available on the svn log command but the [SVN 1.6 documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html) (and 1.5, for that matter), no longer seem to have these parameters. Is it still possible? Any other thoughts on running the command under an identity that ***isn't*** the current account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running `svn help log,` it looks like

`--username AR`G and `--password ARG` are `Global options`.

Same mentioned in the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw) as well.